# jQuery , add class to button if all inputs are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im not the best at javascript, and i'm having trouble making my form disabled unless all my input fields are not empty.

And I will add other things, like making sure the email is an email and password is a minimum of 8 etc.. , but for now I just want to get it working if all inputs are not empty and the terms and conditions checkbox is checked.

This is my code:

```
$('.m-name').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-email').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-password').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-password-confirm').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-terms').change(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});

function monthlyButtonActive()
{
    var complete = 0;
    if($('.m-name').val().length > 2){
        complete++;
    }else{
        complete = 0
    }
    if($('.m-email').val().length > 2){
        complete++;
    }else{
        complete = 0
    }
    if($('.m-password').val().length > 2){
        complete++;
    }else{
        complete = 0
    }
    if($('.m-password-confirm').val().length > 2){
        complete++;
    }else{
        complete = 0
    }
    if($('.m-terms').is(':checked')){
        complete++;
    }else{
        complete = 0
    }
    if(complete == 5){
        console.log(complete);
        console.log('its now complete');
        $('.monthly-button').children('.orange-button').addClass('active-button');
    }else{
        $('.monthly-button').children('.orange-button').addClass('active-button');
    }
```

So if all the fields are not empty , i add a class onto the button of '.active-button' but if not i want to take the class of it. But its not working how I want it too.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the previous class and then adding the new class? Or Considering adding and Id to button element?

Comment: if complete is 5 Do this else do the same, is a bit senseless

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems since you make complete=0 if the field is empty. you shouldn't do anything. If it is not empty you raise complete variable else complete remains the same.

```
$('.m-name').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-email').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-password').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-password-confirm').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-terms').change(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});

function monthlyButtonActive()
{
    var m_name=0,m_email=0,m_password=0,m_password_confirm=0,m_terms=0;
    if($('.m-name').val().length > 2){
        m_name=1;
    }
    if($('.m-email').val().length > 2){
        m_email=1;
    }
    if($('.m-password').val().length > 2){
        m_password=1;
    }
    if($('.m-password-confirm').val().length > 2){
        m_password_confirm=1;
    }
    if($('.m-terms').is(':checked')){
        m_terms=1;
    }
    if(m_name==1&&m_email==1&&,m_password==1&&m_password_confirm==1&&m_terms==1){
        console.log(complete);
        console.log('its now complete');
        $('.monthly-button').children('.orange-button').addClass('active-button');
    }else{
        console.log(complete);
        console.log('its not complete');
    }
```

Comment: Ive just though though, it happens on keyup, so if i type 5 letters into name the complete is already on 5, and then would be 9 after checkbox is clicked

Comment: check the updated answer. that will fix that problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.m-name').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-email').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-password').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-password-confirm').keyup(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});
$('.m-terms').change(function(){monthlyButtonActive();});

function monthlyButtonActive()
{
    var complete = 1;
    if($('.m-name').val().length<=2){           
        complete = 0
    }
    else if($('.m-email').val().length <=2){           
        complete = 0
    }
    else if($('.m-password').val().length<=2){          
        complete = 0
    }
    else if($('.m-password-confirm').val().length <=2){           
        complete = 0
    }
    else if($('.m-terms').is(':checked')==false){            
        complete = 0
    }
    if(complete == 1){
        console.log(complete);
        console.log('its now complete');
        $('.monthly-button').children('.orange-button').removeClass('deactive-button').addClass('active-button');
    }else{
        $('.monthly-button').children('.orange-button').removeClass('active-button').addClass('deactive-button');
    }
```

Comment: why my answer is not useful. i have checked.